# Print 2D table array with 1D array together

Tags: java

How can I possibly print this into table form.

this is my code:

```
 public class TdArrayPrice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] flvr= {"","Cookies n' Cream","Okinawa         ","Dark Chocolate  ","Wintermelon     
        ","Matcha          "};
        double [][] price={ {0,0,0,},
                            {0,100.00,50.00},
                            {0,125.00,75.00},
                            {0,120.00,65.00},
                            {0,120.00,65.00},
                            {0,120.00,65.00}};
        
            for(int i=1; i<6; i++) {
                System.out.println("["+i+"] "+flvr[i]);
                for(int j=1; j<price[i].length; j++) {
                out.print(+price[i][j]+"\t");
            }
            }
        
    }

}
```

I want my output to be look like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWtXV.png
I hope you guys could help me, cause I've been trying to work with it for like tons of days.

Comment: You should read about printf(). (System.out.printf()) Or Format.

Answer (score 1):

### Fixing functionality

I really liked your attempt to solve the problem, it was *almost* correct. Let's see what was wrong:

```java
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    System.out.println("["+i+"] "+flvr[i]);
    for (int j = 1; j < price[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(+price[i][j]+ "\t");
    }
}
```

1. In the first print, you're using `println`, so the prices will be one line below of the coffee name. Change it to `print`.
2. After you print the prices, you're not adding a new line, so the next coffee and its prices will be printed in the same line as the previous one. Add a `println` to the outer loop.

Fixed code:

```java
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    System.out.print("["+i+"] "+flvr[i]);
    for (int j = 1; j < price[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(+price[i][j]+ "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
[1] Cookies n' Cream100.0   50.0    
[2] Okinawa125.0    75.0    
[3] Dark Chocolate120.0 65.0    
[4] Wintermelon120.0    65.0    
[5] Matcha120.0 65.0
```

### Formatting improvements

You can use `System.out.printf` to add some padding to the coffee name and prices instead of `'\t'`:

```java
// Print the header
System.out.printf("%-23s%10s %11s\n", "MILKTEA FLAVORS", "Large", "Small");
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    // Add a right padding of 20 spaces in the coffee name
    System.out.printf("[%d] %-20s", i, flvr[i]);
    for (int j = 1; j < price[i].length; j++) {
        // Add a left padding of 10 spaces in each price
        System.out.printf("%10.2f ", price[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

New output:

```
MILKTEA FLAVORS             Large       Small
[1] Cookies n' Cream        100.00      50.00 
[2] Okinawa                 125.00      75.00 
[3] Dark Chocolate          120.00      65.00 
[4] Wintermelon             120.00      65.00 
[5] Matcha                  120.00      65.00
```

### Data representation

Since Java is an object-oriented language, you can use objects to represent each coffee.

```java
class Coffee {
    final String name;
    final double largePrice;
    final double smallPrice;

    public Coffee(String name, double largePrice, double smallPrice) {
        this.name = name;
        this.largePrice = largePrice;
        this.smallPrice = smallPrice;
    }
}
```

Instantiating them:

```java
final Coffee[] coffees = {
    new Coffee("Cookies n' Cream", 100.00, 50.00),
    new Coffee("Okinawa", 125.0, 75.0),
    new Coffee("Dark Chocolate", 120.0, 65.0),
    new Coffee("Wintermelon", 120.0, 65.0),
    new Coffee("Matcha", 120.0, 65.0),
};
```

Printing them:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < coffees.length; i++) {
    final Coffee coffee = coffees[i];
    System.out.printf("[%d] %-20s", i, coffee.name);
    System.out.printf("%10.2f ", coffee.largePrice);
    System.out.printf("%10.2f", coffee.smallPrice);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: THANK YA'LLLLL GUYSS!!! I REALLY DO APPRECIATE YA'LL. I JUST STARTED LEARNING NEW THINGS IN PROGRAMMING. YOU GUYS ARE TRULY AWESOME :>

Comment: That's *really* nice to hear, hope you have a great future in programming. If my answer helped you in any way, you can always [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the power of String.format() in detail. It's worth it - regardless if you use printf or String.format or even other programming languages like C/C++ printf statements.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)